# Unexpected Scala pattern matching syntax

Tags: scala, syntax, pattern-matching

I had a List of Scala tuples like the following:

```
val l = List((1,2),(2,3),(3,4))
```

and I wanted to map it in a list of Int where each item is the sum of the Ints in a the corresponding tuple. I also didn't want to use to use the x._1 notation so I solved the problem with a pattern matching like this

```
def addTuple(t: (Int, Int)) : Int = t match { 
    case (first, second) => first + second 
}
var r = l map addTuple
```

Doing that I obtained the list r: List[Int] = List(3, 5, 7) as expected. At this point, almost by accident, I discovered that I can achieve the same result with an abbreviated form like the following:

```
val r = l map {case(first, second) => first + second}
```

I cannot find any reference to this syntax in the documentation I have. Is that normal? Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: This syntax is nice, but for eays things like this I prefer l.map(t => t._1 + t._2). I think there is nothing wrong with the x._1 syntax

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See Section 8.5 of the language reference, "Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions".

> An anonymous function can be defined by a sequence of cases
>
> `{case p1 =>b1 ... case pn => bn }`
>
> which appear as an expression without a prior match. The expected type of such an expression must in part be defined. It must be either `scala.Functionk[S1, ..., Sk, R]` for some `k` > 0, or `scala.PartialFunction[S1, R]`, where the argument type(s) `S1, ..., Sk` must be fully determined, but the result type `R` may be undetermined.

The expected type deternines whether this is translated to a `FunctionN` or `PartialFunction`.

```
scala> {case x => x}  
<console>:6: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x0$1) => x0$1 match {
  case (x @ _) => x
})
       {case x => x}
       ^

scala> {case x => x}: (Int => Int)
res1: (Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> {case x => x}: PartialFunction[Int, Int]
res2: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = <function1>
```

Answer (score 4):

`{case(first, second) => first + second}` is treated as a `PartialFunction` literal. See examples in "Partial Functions" section here: http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch08.html or section 15.7 of *Programming in Scala*.

Answer (score 1):

Method `map` accepts a function. In your first example you create a function, assign it to a variable, and pass it to the `map` method. In the second example you pass your created function directly, omitting assigning it to a variable. You are doing just the same thing.

Comment: Not precisely. In the first example, the *method* `addTuple` is defined. The compiler then uses *partial application* to generate an equivalent function which is passed to the `map` method invoked on `l`.