# 'case' keyword appearing without its corresponding 'match' keyword

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am going through one Scala example in one of the popular Spark books. It looks strange to me, at least as a newbie. I know how a standard match/case construct in Scala looks like in Scala. But in this example I see 'case' is being used without corresponding 'match' keyword. Is it even valid? Or more of a typo in the book?

```
val joined = userData.join(events)// RDD of (UserID, (UserInfo, LinkInfo)) pairs
val offTopicVisits = joined.filter {
case (userId, (userInfo, linkInfo)) => !userInfo.topics.contains(linkInfo.topic)
}.count()
```

So if it's not a regular match/case, is the 'case' being used in some other context?

Thanks

Comment: The wording is slightly different, but the question is pretty much the same. See also: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478244/how-does-a-case-anonymous-function-really-work-in-scala) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730811/unexpected-scala-pattern-matching-syntax/3730879#3730879)

Answer (score 2):

That's called [pattern matching anonymous functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions) in the Scala specification where the prior `match` can be dropped for the same behaviour.

```
{ case p1 => b1 … case pn => bn }
```

is equivalent to:

```
(x1:S1,…,xk:Sk) => (x1,…,xk) match {
  case p1 => b1 … case pn => bn
}
```

which in turn is equivalent to:

```
new scala.Functionk[S1,…,Sk, T] {
  def apply(x1:S1,…,xk:Sk): T = (x1,…,xk) match {
    case p1 => b1 … case pn => bn
  }
}
```

unless the expected type is a partial function:

```
new scala.PartialFunction[S, T] {
  def apply(x: S): T = x match {
    case p1 => b1 … case pn => bn
  }
  def isDefinedAt(x: S): Boolean = {
    case p1 => true … case pn => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```